# To Upload a file object to a web service in windows 8.1 javascript store app

Tags: javascript, ajax, windows-store-apps, blob, multipartform-data

I need to post a file which is inside apps local folder to a web service.

The problem is the web service accepts only file object. I have generated a blob instead of file object and tried posting via Ajax as multipart request, but the service is not accepting the request.

```
    var fileee;
    window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder ||
    window.WebKitBlobBuilder ||
    window.MozBlobBuilder ||
    window.MSBlobBuilder;
    if (window.BlobBuilder) {
       var bb = new BlobBuilder();
       bb.append(contents);
       fileee = bb.getBlob(mimeType);
    }

    fileee.fileId = FileID;
    fileee.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    fileee.name = actualFileName;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", fileee);   
    $.ajax({
         url: serverUrl,
         data: formData,
         cache: false,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         type: 'POST',
         beforeSend: function (xhr) {      
            xhr.setRequestHeader("accessToken", accessToken);
         },
         success: function (result) {
             //do something
         },
         error: function (result) {
             //do something
         }
    });
```

Please help me out in generating the file object from the storage file i.e the file which is inside apps local folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The webservice shouldn't know or care if you're using a File object or a Blob object. BlobBuilder... this code must be really old, BlobBuilder has been obsolete for a while. Adding fields to Blob object will have no effect whatsoever. You can add fields to the request with FormData.append, also you can add a filename to the blob when adding it using the third parameter. `formData.append("file", fileee,actualFileName); `

Comment: Thanks @Musa, `formData.append("file", fileee,actualFileName);` This worked for me :)  [With this reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file) `var fileObject=new File(ArrayBuffer,actualFileName);` I was trying to construct file object from ArrayBuffer which is not supported in IE. But the Blob with name is a file object as you mentioned. Thanks once again.